# How can I disable Intel Turboboost and Hyper-Threading?

Tags: catalina, cpu, macos, turbo-boost

The title pretty much sums it up but I need a way to disable Turboboost and Hyper-Threading. I am currently on macOS Catalina and I am able to edit system files because I have SIP disabled. I am ok with the solution not being permanent (meaning that it resets upon reboot). I have used https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6262465 as a reference and it didn't work for me. Most of these solutions on the internet have stopped working after OS X Yosemite.

Please only answer this question if you will be providing a solution, not telling me to leave hyper-threading on.

By the way, this question is not a duplicate because most other question only ask how to do it on OS X Yosemite and below when Apple had tools to do this.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? Perhaps there's another way of achieving your goal.

Comment: I need to reduce the power usage of my Mac and Apple Support confirmed that Hyper-Threading and Turboboost are causing a lot of energy to be consumed.

Comment: @benwiggy what other way can I use to achieve advertised 11 hours of wireless web on my 2.4kilobuck MacBook Pro 16" 2019 that gets from 100% battery to 0% in under 2 hours of wireless web?

Comment: @cnst That sounds like a new question. You'd need to rule out faulty hardware and unusual software, as that's clearly not an expected amount of time. Disabling HT and TB may improve your battery life, but it may not be the best fix to restore your MBP to more normal operation.

Comment: @benwiggy I don't think you understood the question. I didn't say that my MacBook Pro wasn't operating normally. I said that I needed to disable hyperthreading and turboboost to improve battery life. cnst is right about there being no other solution, especially after I included in my previous comment that Apple Support has confirmed hyper-threading and turboboost to be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do this. It does result in a 40% performance drop.

Apple has documentation that disables Hyper-Threading with the following:
Boot into macOS Recovery
In Terminal: `nvram boot-args="cwae=2"` and `nvram SMTDisable=%01`
Click  and Restart.

To revert this, reset the NVRAM.

Here is the official documentation: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT210108

Comment: Installing those apps don't work anymore, however this solution still works.

Comment: Good find, but that only disables hyper threading; my understanding is that it's actually Turbo Boost that's most detrimental to battery life; although I couldn't find any good comparison on the subject -- lack of these tools to properly disable these nuisances is probably the reason why testing isn't really being done in the mainstream.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the useful tools / notes for reigning in macOS Catalina 10.15 running on MacBook Pro 16" 2019 monstrosity:

- ### Intel Hyper-Threading

It appears possible to use Apple's ***`cpuctl`*** to take some of the CPUs offline; it looks like an internal tool supplied by Apple; there's no easy way to know which CPUs are hyperthreading ones (I think they're supposed to be the even ones), so, a safe bet may be to disable half of the upper even-numbered CPUs, to effectively disable 1/2 of Hyper-Threading, e.g., on a 6-core machine with 12 virtual CPUs, we can disable 3 of them rather safely:

```
sudo cpuctl offline 7 9 11 ; sudo cpuctl list
```

Can also use the ***CPUSetter*** from whatroute.net; which has a setting dedicated to specifically disabling Hyper Threading; which results in all even-numbered CPUs being taken offline.

- ### Intel Turbo Boost

Turbo Boost is most definitely the most power-hungry and useless technology that cannot be easily disabled on a Mac.  It would seem that the ***Turbo Boost Switcher*** from rugarciap.com can be made to work on macOS Catalina 10.15 after some troubleshooting, but it's kind of buggy, and the free version keeps requiring you to enter a password each time upon a wakeup.

- #### Verifying that Turbo Boost got disabled

You can use ***Intel Power Gadget*** from Intel to monitor actual CPU frequency; and verify that it doesn't go above the spec, e.g., on MacBook Pro 16" 2019 w/ a 6-core i7-9750H, doesn't go above the regular 2.6GHz up to 4.5GHz Turbo.

- ### Graphics and Transparency

Go to System Preferences, Accessibility, Display, and turn on all the options to "Reduce motion", "Increase contrast" (incl. "Reduce Transparency"), "Differentiate without color".

Also, go to System Settings, Dock, and select "Minimize windows using:" "Scale effect" (instead of "Genie effect").

- ### Excessive Heat

You should also use ***Macs Fan Control*** from crystalidea.com if you want to be able to use your 2.4 kilobuck laptop on your lap without being extremely uncomfortable from the excessive heat.

Answer (score 0):

I did see  [Turbo Boost Switcher Pro for Mac](https://gumroad.com/l/YeBQUF) recently, which switches off TurboBoost.

> - Disable Turbo Boost when charger is disconnected.
> - Disable Turbo Boost when battery level goes below a configurable setting and/or depending on remaining time estimation.
> - Enable / Disable turbo boost when the selected app is running.
> - Choose Turbo Boost enabled default mode (On or Off).

Comment: That tool can be made to work on macOS Catalina 10.15 after some troubleshooting, but it's quite buggy, and the free version always nags you for a password every time you machine wakes up, which is pretty annoying.  I wish there was something to simply disable Turbo Boost permanently w/o any of this BS.